# download subdirectory/directory from blob storage using nodejs and blob service?

Tags: node.js, azure-blob-storage

I have implemented download files using getBlobProperties() and createReadStream(containerName, fullPath, options) methods of blob service. now, I am trying to download directory/subdirectory inside my containers using the same methods but it is not working, and throwing error, specified blob does not exist. though I know the reason for this error how Can I overcome this issue as I don't want to loop the blobs and download each file separately?. I want a complete folder to be downloaded.

here is the API:

```
exports.getBlobChunk = function (req, res) {
var userrole = utils.sanitizeStr(req.body.userrole);
var srcFilePath = utils.sanitizeStr(req.body.srcfilePath);
var fileName = utils.sanitizeStr(req.body.srcfileName);
var fullPath = srcFilePath + "/" + fileName;
var startRange = req.headers['startrange'];
var endRange = req.headers['endrange'];
genericHandler.getUserSubscMapping().then(function (results) {
if (results != undefined && results != null) {
var item = results[0].mapping.find(item => item.name == userrole);
var sasurl = item.sasurl;
if (sasurl == null) {
res.status(500).send("Subscription mapping not configured");
return;
}
var host = sasurl.substring(0, sasurl.lastIndexOf("/"));
var containerName = sasurl.substring(sasurl.lastIndexOf("/"), sasurl.indexOf("?")).split("/")[1];
var saskey = sasurl.substring(sasurl.indexOf("?"), sasurl.length);
var download = item.download; // download usage
var blobService = storage.createBlobServiceWithSas(host, saskey);
blobService.getBlobProperties(containerName, fullPath, function (err, properties, status) {
if (err) {
res.send(502, "Error fetching file: %s", err.message);
} else if (!status.isSuccessful) {
res.send(404, "The file %s does not exist", fullPath);
} else {
var contentLength = properties.contentLength / 1024; // bytes to KB
res.header('Content-Type', "application/zip");
res.attachment(fileName);
var options = {
rangeStart: startRange,
rangeEnd: endRange
};
if (startRange == 0) { // update download size on first chunk
exports.updateStorageDownload(userrole, contentLength, download);
}
blobService.createReadStream(containerName, fullPath, options).pipe(res);
}
});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Azure Blob storage **does not have a concept of folders** and everything inside the container is considered a blob including the folders. So you couldn't download directory/subdirectory with folder name.

For example:

- Container structure

  ```
    hello.txt
    ...
    test
        test.txt
        test1
            data.json
  ```

You need to download blob file from directory one by one.

```
const {
  BlobServiceClient,
  StorageSharedKeyCredential,
} = require("@azure/storage-blob");

// Enter your storage account name and shared key
const account = "";
const accountKey ="";
const containerName = "";
const filePath = "D:/downloads/"

// Use StorageSharedKeyCredential with storage account and account key
// StorageSharedKeyCredential is only available in Node.js runtime, not in browsers
const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey);
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
  `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
  sharedKeyCredential,
);


async function listBlobs() {
  const containerClient = await blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
  console.log("list blobs with method listBlobsFlat");
  let iter = containerClient.listBlobsFlat({ prefix: "test/" });
  for await (const item of iter) {
    console.log(`\tBlobItem: name - ${item.name}`);
    downloadBlobToLocal(containerClient, item.name, filePath);
  }
  console.log("list blobs with method listBlobsByHierarchy");
  let iter1 = containerClient.listBlobsByHierarchy("/", { prefix: "test/" });
  for await (const item of iter1) {
    if (item.kind === "prefix") {
      console.log(`\tBlobPrefix: ${item.name}`);
      await listblob(containerClient, item.name);
    } else {
      console.log(`\tBlobItem: name - ${item.name}`);
      downloadBlobToLocal(containerClient, item.name, filePath);
    }
  }
}

async function listblob(containerClient, prefix) {
  let iter1 = containerClient.listBlobsByHierarchy("/", { prefix: prefix });
  for await (const item of iter1) {
    if (item.kind === "prefix") {
      console.log(`\tBlobPrefix: ${item.name}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`\tBlobItem: name - ${item.name}`);
      downloadBlobToLocal(containerClient, item.name, filePath);
    }
  }
}

async function downloadBlobToLocal(containerClient, blobName, filePath) {
    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
    const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.downloadToFile(filePath + blobName);
}

listBlobs().catch((err) => {
  console.error("Error running sample:", err.message);
});
```

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Comment: Hi pamela, I am able to download files .I am looking for solution to download folders for which this code will not resolve my concern .

Comment: Do you mean to download the empty folder(like 'test' in my structure)?

Comment: **Azure Blob storage does not have a concept of folders.** For example, the blob name of `test.txt` in structure is `test/test.txt`. `test` itself is meaningless, you can not download it. So if you want to download both "folder" and files(means blobs), you need to download `test/test.txt` to loacl path `xxx/test/test.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

I've written my own implementation based on [this](https://blog.christian-schou.dk/how-to-use-azure-blob-storage-with-asp-net-core/) great article:

```
public async Task<List<BlobDto>> ListWithPrefixAsync(string folder)
        {
            // Get a reference to a container named in appsettings.json
            BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(_storageConnectionString, _storageContainerName);

            // Create a new list object for 
            List<BlobDto> files = new List<BlobDto>();

            await foreach (BlobItem file in container.GetBlobsAsync(prefix: folder))
            {
                // Add each file retrieved from the storage container to the files list by creating a BlobDto object
                string uri = container.Uri.ToString();
                var name = file.Name;
                var fullUri = $"{uri}/{name}";

                files.Add(new BlobDto
                {
                    Uri = fullUri,
                    Name = name,
                    ContentType = file.Properties.ContentType
                });
            }

            // Return all files to the requesting method
            return files;
        }
```

The implementation to get the list of blob files in a folder is then very simply like that:

```
// Get all files at the Azure Storage Location and return them
        List<BlobDto>? files = await _storage.ListWithPrefixAsync(prefix);
```

Hope this helps.

Happy coding!!